# Table of contents using article and report classes

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, document-classes

When I make a table of contents with the `article` and `report` classes the results are different. I have two questions.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I make the `report` ToC look like the `article` one?

Here are a pair of examples:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243822/117400

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, the "top-level" entries in a table of contents will be typeset in bold and without a dotted line between entry name and page number. For the article class, the "top level" is `\section`, while for the report (and the book) class it's `\chapter`. Simply changing `\section` to `\chapter` in your first example will result in (roughly) the same TOC layout.

Answer (score 10):

1. The report class has been designed for typesetting large documents with chapters in contrary to the article class which doesn't support chapters. That's why reports may contain more extensive TOCs containing more sectioning levels, thus a different layout could be meaningful.
2. Consider to use a package to design the table of contents, for instance [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc).

Comment: By default, in the report class, the `tocdepth` counter is set to 2 (so that the "lowest-ranking" heading going into the TOC is `\subsection`), while in the article class `tocdepth` is 3 (so that a `\subsubsection` will make it into the TOC). It seems Leslie Lamport didn't have different TOC layouts for report vs. article in mind.

Comment: @lockstep: good point :) at least the report's TOC has a "chapter look" regarding heading and its spacing.