# LaTeX report - table of contents without chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, report

I am trying to write a LaTeX report (using class `report`) but I don't want to use chapters, only sections, subsections and subsub. Using

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}},
```

my sections numbering now start at 1 and not 0.1, which is what I wanted. However, my table of contents keep the 0 before the 1 (eg 0.1 "Title") meant for the chapter numbering. How can I remove it ?

I know that the class article doesn't have chapters and could be a solution but is there a way to remove those 0 before the 1 in the table of contents without using the article class ?

Thanks for your answers

edit : this is what I did :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %I want the subsubsection in my ToC
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\section{first section}

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annexes} % I want the appendix title in my ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section*{Annexes}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} % And the numbering with letters
\subsection{first appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although the question is quite clear, it's better to provide some small sample document to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use the `report` class; is there any particular reason? However, I get just the section number in the TOC, in my experiment. Can you add a minimal example?

Comment: no particular reason for the report class, I just thought it was better suited for an internship report

Comment: I think you simply forgot to compile it twice, since it works the way you want without adding `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}`

Comment: @Sterry why should I compile it twice for it to work ?

Comment: @etienne: LaTeX can't know in advance how many sections etc. there would be. The first run stores the information, the second run uses this information to typeset the table of contents. If you have a book without `toc` you have to look for the chapters/sections too and count them yourself before you know the number ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for most cases:

**Edit** Meanwhile there is a MWE by the OP. Probably, the OP forgot to compile twice.

```
\documentclass{report}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First} \label{firstsection}
\subsection{First section} \label{firstsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In general, `article` class would be easier, in this case

Comment: I get no `0` even without redefining `\thechapter`

Comment: @egreg: Right, it's not necessary at all. I believe, I changed the 'mwe' by the OP somehow, probably between the first and 2nd run.